# I can't use libraries installed with paket tool

Tags: .net, f#, paket, dotnet-tool

I can't `open` namespaces of libraries i added via paket and use them. If i try to build the project, the compiler complains with

```
error FS0039: The namespace 'bla bla' is not defined. [path of fsproj]
```

But i can clearly see them added in **paket.dependencies**, **paket.references** and **paket.lock**. So what is wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be caused because of paket's default framework restrictions and your dotnet version mismatch. For example; as of date 2021-12-27 and paket version 6.2.1 when you `paket init`, by default in **paket.dependencies** file there is this line:

```
framework: net5.0, netstandard2.0, netstandard2.1
```

If your dotnet version is **6.0**, you can't use any library you added.

Solution is simple: just add `net6.0` to that line.

```
framework: net6.0, net5.0, netstandard2.0, netstandard2.1
```

and then run

```
paket update
dotnet restore
```

(Running `dotnet restore` helps with your editor's linting). If there is no other problem, this should fix the situation.

Comment: Awesome! That's it! You saved my life!